# Reorder values when storing from NEON registers

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I have 128 32-bit values (numbered from 0 to 127) and have them ordered in the following way:

0, 32, 64, 96, 1, 33, 65, 97, ... 31, 63, 95, 127

With this ordering I load them in groups of 4 into NEON registers to perform some computation (which requires such ordering). 
Thus I have `q0 = (0, 32, 64, 96)` ... and so on.

I was wondering if there's some easy way storing them back to the memory in their natural order (0 1 2 3 ...)

In other words, is there some easier way or a trick to do this:

```
vst1.u32 {d0[0]}, [r0]
vst1.u32 {d0[1]}, [r0,#128]
vst1.u32 {d1[0]}, [r0,#256]
vst1.u32 {d1[1]}, [r0,#384]
vst1.u32 {d2[0]}, [r0,#4]
vst1.u32 {d2[1]}, [r0,#132]
...
```

I dont quite understand the use of `@alignment` suffix with `vstx` and `vldx` instructions. Isn't this a case where it could be useful?

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid, but your ordering starts with 1, 32, 64, 96; (+31,+32,+32), shouldn't it end with   
31,62,94,126,  
32,63,95,127,  
33,64,96,128?

Comment: Thanks! Of course it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment (@128, @256) is used to hint the processor that the read/write does not cross a cache line. In those cases the number of executed micro-operations (and eventually used cycles) can be reduced.

Your application would instead benefit from the instruction format that allows storing / loading columns. Arm manual calls these *lanes* as in subsection ([Store a single lane of N-element structure to memory](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDDHDG.html)).

The format supports both consecutive registers: {d0,d1,d2,...} and skipping over one register {d0,d2,d4,...}.

```
 mov #128, r1  // initialize value for increment
 vst4.32 { d0[0], d2[0], d4[0], d6[0] }, [r0], r1   // columns 0..1
 vst4.32 { d0[1], d2[1], d4[1], d6[1] }, [r0], r1   // store at offset 128
 vst4.32 { d1[0], d3[0], d5[0], d7[0] }, [r0], r1   // columns 2..3
 vst4.32 { d1[1], d3[1], d5[1], d7[1] }, [r0], r1   // columns 2..3
 ... etc ...
```

This is probably the best one can do, as there are not enough registers to shuffle everything in place. I believe one would need 32 Q-registers.

Comment: This is nice. But could you explain what dx[2] and dx[3] is? I thought that dx is 64 bit wide thus it has only dx[0] and dx[1] (lower 32-bit and higher 32-bit halves respectively)

Comment: You also forgot to decrement r0, since suffixed increments are permanent. Anyway, I modified my code and it works pretty well so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Right you are, there are no 32-bit indices d_even[2..3]. Those would actually be d_odd[0..1]. Anyway I just wanted to provide some conceptual code.